# If $f(x)$ is differentiable at $0$, is the function $g(x)=f(x)x$ then $2$-times differentiable at $0$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, taylor-expansion

My thought process was that with Taylor's formula we can write
$$f(x)=f(0)+f'(0)x+h(x)x$$
and therefore we have
$$g(x)=f(0)x+f'(0)x^2+h(x)x^2$$
Comparing the coefficients my guess was that $g(x)$ is $2$-times differentiable at $0$ with $g'(0)=f(0), g''(0)=2f'(0)$ but I dont know how to prove this. Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: No. The function $f(x) = x^2 \cdot 1_{\mathbb{Q}}(x)$ is differentiable at (only at) zero. The derivative does not exist for $x \neq 0$ so there can be no second derivative.

Comment: @copper.hat Does it become true if $f$ is differentiable in a neighborhood of $0$?

Comment: @eyeballfrog Yes if $f'$ is also continuous at $x=0$, see my answer.

Comment: @copper.hat Depends on what you mean by "second derivative" (well, not for your function, but for, say, $x^3\cdot 1_{\Bbb Q}(x)$). If it is defined as twice the second degree second degree coefficient of the unique second degree polynomial which best estimates the function (if there is a "good enough" estimation), then the second derivative can exist even though the function is only differentiable in a single point. If you define the second derivative as the derivative of the first derivative (which, granted, is more common), then I agree with you.

Comment: If we do not state that $f(x)$ is twice differentiable, there is no way that $xf(x)$ will be

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need an extra assumption, I might be mistaken. Assume $f$ is differentiable in a small neighborhood $I$ of $0$ and that $f'$ is continuous at $0$.

You have if $x\in I$
$$g'(x)=f'(x)x+f(x)$$
hence $g'(0)=f(0)$. Then if $x\in I, x\not=0$:
$$\dfrac{g'(x)-g'(0)}{x}=\dfrac{f'(x)x+f(x)-f(0)}{x}=f'(x)+\dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}$$
If $f'$ is continuous at $0$ then
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{g'(x)-g'(0)}{x}=2f'(0)$$
and $g''$ is twice differentiable at $0$.

Comment: If I calculated correctly then a concrete counterexample is $f(x) = x^2 \sin(1/x)$.

Comment: Does $f'$ need to be continuous at $0$ though?

Comment: @zugzug Seems like it since I use that $f'(x)\rightarrow f'(0)$ as $x\rightarrow 0$. I think that there exist differentiable functions such that $f'$ is nowhere continuous by a Baire argument.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a formal proof. But I do not think you are actually asking for one. Note that if $g(x) = xf(x)$ then:
\begin{align} 
g'(x) &= f(x) + xf'(x), \\
g''(x) &= f'(x) + f'(x) + xf''(x).
\end{align}

Since you do not know whether $f''(x)$ exists. You do not know whether $g(x)$ is twice differentiable at 0.

Maybe this was also better suited as comment. If so, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

I think your confusion stems from the fact that a function $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ if and only if there is a real coefficient $C$ such that $f(x)-f(x_0)=+C(x-x_0)+o(x-x_0)$; and in such case $C=f'(x_0)$ of course.

The problem is that the natural generalization to the second order is false, i.e. it is not true that $f(x)-f(x_0)=C(x-x_0)^2+o\bigl((x-x_0)^2\bigr)$ implies the existence of the second derivative at $x_0$. The issue is that the existence of $f''(x_0)$ requires the existence of $f'$ in a neighborhood, whereas a function satisfying the above bound need not even be continuous around $x_0$.